# Iam tagging an image, after pulling it from Dockerhub

Tags: python, docker, docker-registry, docker-tag

> Iam tagging an image, after pulling it from Dockerhub. the tag here takes the original image tag. so my Question is how to add the word (local_) before the tag.

```
def tag_images(images, image_names):
print('====Tagging Images====')

for image, image_name in zip(images, image_names):
    iname, itag = get_name_and_tag(image_name)
    image.tag(repository=f'{REGISTRY_IP}:{REGISTRY_PORT}/{iname}',
              tag=itag)
    print(
        f'Successfully Tagged: {iname}:local_{itag} as {REGISTRY_IP}:{REGISTRY_PORT}/{iname}:local_{itag}')

print(f'====Tagged {len(images)} Images====')
```

Comment: how about just change this line `image.tag(repository=f'{REGISTRY_IP}:{REGISTRY_PORT}/{iname}', tag="local_"+itag)`

Comment: Perfect . thanks bro. i appreciate it

Answer (score 0):

@Maxm Answer:

image.tag(repository=f'{REGISTRY_IP}:{REGISTRY_PORT}/{iname}', tag="local_"+itag)

and it works